# Migrating Remote CVS to local Git on OSX

Tags: git, macos, migration, cvs

I am trying to migrate a simple remote cvs repository to GIT on Eclipse Mars on an OSX machine.
I have installed a command line cvs and logged in to the remote cvs server.
I then tried running the following:-
**$ git cvsimport -v -a -i -k -d :pserver:lyndon@xxxx.com:/home/mmj/cvs/repos -C cvstest cvstest**

But it fails with this output:
**Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/xxxx/git/cvstest/.git/
Running cvsps...
bad usage: invalid argument --norc**

Any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

> In cvsps 3.10 the flag --norc was removed. It broke 'git cvsimport'.

([Source](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/cvsps-bad-usage-invalid-argument-norc-td7582621.html))

So just downgrade your `cvsps`. Version 2 worked for me. Example for homebrew:

```
brew unlink cvsps # temporarily disable version 3
brew tap Frizlab/Perso && brew install cvsps@2 # install older version

# run cvsimport, should work

# remove old version + enable newer version:
brew uninstall cvsps@2
brew link cvsps
```

Comment: @saladi Looks like that `Frizlab/Perso` tap is no longer valid.  I get some stuff about `Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/frizlab/homebrew-perso/Formula/ruby@2.4.1.rb` when I try to add it.